# how to add $HOME variable in apache DocumentRoot

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

how can i make apache documentroot like

> DocumentRoot $HOME/var/www

It is showing invalid path error.

Comment: Iirc HOME is unset in the init script of apache. Btw. what HOME do you expect? - Maybe you wnt to use mod_userdir?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're looking for a way to serve files from users' home directories, have a look at this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:
${HOME} instead of $HOME

See also:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax

That may still not solve your problem, it may be that $HOME is not defined in this context or if it is it is pointing to an non-existent directory. Try running:
apachectl configtest

to make sure everything looks ok.